# UIView size not updating with dynamic UILabels

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a NIB and constraint based UIView containing several UILabel children. Each UILabel has a line number of 0 to set it to be dynamic.

In my particular case, I'm using this UIView as a header (**not** a section header) for a UITableView. The UIView correctly draws as if it expanded to fit the UILabels, however the UIView's frame isn't updated to it's new size, thus the table cells clip under the bottom of the table header.

How can I get it to properly update the frame as the UILabels change in size?

Comment: Have you looked into the UITableViewDelegate method tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:? If the UIView that you are using as the header view is resizing correctly (which I would check using NSLog(@"view:%@", myHeaderView); then returning the height of that frame in tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: should *i think* resize the header to the appropriate height.

Comment: Actually it's a table header, not a section table header. Appreciate the help though!

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Are you sure the UIView's frame isn't changing? Have you logged the view to look at its origin and size? Maybe you just need to set the content offset of your table view when the size of the labels/headerView change?

Comment: Yep. I put logged the parent view and the child label before and after I set the text. The label's frame height expands, however the frame height for the parent view stays the same. I think I've tried just about every update layout call I can on the parent view, but to no avail.